# Why is the JSONParser always returning a double?

Tags: java, codenameone

I am currently trying to use the JSONParser of the codename on api.

On the backend side there is a long value send, but in my application there is a double value parsed.

I know that there is a method saying *setUseLongs(boolean)* and I already set that field to true. If I instanciate the Parser and call *System.out.println(p.isUseLong)* it prints *true*.

However, the field is still parsed as a double value, though it is send as a long value.

What am I missing here?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    JSONParser.setUseLongs(true);
    JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
    System.out.println(p.isUseLongs());  //true and a Warning to use static methods static...
    Map<String,Object> data = p.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
    System.out.println(data);  //long value already printed as double
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the JSON String (printed in the last line, the parsers output):

```
[
{createdByUserId=1364.0, //should be int
createdAtDate=1.464330197735E12, //should be long
deleted=false, //boolean, correct
updatedAtDate=1.464330197735E12, //long 
name=Hallo1, //String, correct
...
]
```

Comment: maybe updating your library  can help  since there was a bug related with this:  https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone/issues/1254

Comment: thank you, updated my libs, refreshed libs, still the same

Comment: It Maybe useful to show us the JSON text.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: That JSON isn't valid - the string isn't quoted. Also I suspect that it won't use longs if the token has a decimal point or exponent, since they usually denote non-integral point numbers.

Comment: @PeteKirkham This is the parsed string of the json parse, sorry for confusion

Answer (score 3):

```
//Assuming all elements are double
createdByUserId.intvalue();
createdAtDate.longValue();
```

`JSONParser` has a [setUseLongs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/JSONParser.html#setUseLongs-boolean-) method which will use long objects for long values and double for double values. This is off by default for compatibility and because of an inconvenience in Codename One.

Currently Codename One doesn't include the `Number` class which is a base class for all numeric values so normally in standard Java you would do something like:

```
long l = ((Number)val).longValue();
```

Which makes more sense as you aren't relying on what the parser returned. Unfortunately, at this time this isn't supported but I added an issue to address that [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1783).

Comment: Right. I added some details to the answer to explain why it's that way

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, @TimWeber This didn't solve my problem. The variable `createdAt` is of type double, but does not have a function `longValue()`

Comment: `double` with lower case d is a primitive type which is autoboxed. Make sure you use `Double` with uppercase.